# How to allow requests to elasticsearch only from a list of ips/domains

Tags: elasticsearch

I read the docs, but I couldn't make it work.

I have a server that holds elasticsearch and external ones that query it. Until now I can access the elasticsearch from any ip.

Example:

the public ip:port of elasticsearchserver: **123.123.123.123:9200**
I have the domains: **anothersocialnetwork.com**  and **anothersocialnetwork2.com**

and I want only them and localhost to be able to query the elasticsearch server.

Thank you alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve this. The one i would like to advice is as follows -

1. Run Elasticsearch in localhost interface by network.host as localhost in elasticsearch.yml file.
2. Now only applications in localhost can access the application
3. Place a proxy like nginx or apache and this proxy would be able to access elasticsearch. Now whitelist the IP's you want to access Elasticsearch in the proxy.

Also you can take a look at [Elasticsearch jetty plugin](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty). It has some security configurations along with it. But i am not sure if its actively developed.

Also on [security Elasticsearch](https://qbox.io/blog/getting-to-know-elasticsearch-securing-your-environment) , i would recommend to go through [this blog](https://qbox.io/blog/getting-to-know-elasticsearch-securing-your-environment).

Comment: is there a more direct way from elasticsearch.yml  to do this ?

Comment: I don't believe there is no direct way to achieve this. I have added one more option in answer.