# Elasticsearch search request restrict to only certain server IPs

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

Is it possible to create a filter of some sort in elasticsearch, such that the search request will be honored only if the request is from trusted IP (certain servers only).

I referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670185/how-to-allow-requests-to-elasticsearch-only-from-a-list-of-ips-domains) however, would like to check if the latest versions has this feature, i couldn't find anything in the elastic document.

Note: i have a more then 1 elastic server in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the network module is what you are looking for.

There are two kind of networks in elasticsearch clusters:

1. Transport: Communication between the nodes of the cluster
2. Http: Communication with all kind of clients

If you want to restrict searches to serveral IPs please have a look on `xpack.security.http.filter.*` settings.

A brief documentation of this feature is available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip-filtering.html).